# Redirect, how to show the result

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, phpstorm, http-redirect

I am new to Laravel; I tried to open an example project in Laravel by using the PhpStorm IDE.

In the web.php file I have the following line

```php
Route::get('/someurl', 'Web\WebPages@someFunction')->name('some_name');
```

In the `WebPages.php` file I have the `someFunction` and inside that I have a "redirect" command

```php
return static::redirect(static::ROUTE, $parameters, $locale, 301);
```

How can I do that? It is possible, to execute just a single line of code (i.e. the first `Route::get`) and see what the redirect produces by some PhpStorm debug feature? And how to show the result in a console / terminal / log? Or it is some other way? I would be just curious to see really in deep how the redirect works.

I am sorry if the question is too much simple, but I am at beginning and my first step after studying some theory is try to analyse directly some case history.

Comment: For starters, you can look at the HTTP response in the "network" tab of your browser debug tools. You'll see that it uses the 301 HTTP code, and contains a URL. What this does is instruct the browser to issue a new request for the new URL.

The redirect itself happens entirely in the browser, all the server does is inform it of the new target.

Comment: use dd(anything you want to output). to see the result produced

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there is an option that could be useful and solve your problem.

You can insert information in the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file as follows:

First import the Log dependency

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

Then you only have to add the content you want to add in the log as follows:

```
Log::emergency($message);
Log::alert($message);
Log::critical($message);
Log::error($message);
Log::warning($message);
Log::notice($message);
Log::info($message);
Log::debug($message);
```

You can find more information in the official [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#writing-log-messages)